# Use gitlab's https link when logged in with Google Account

Tags: git, https, gitlab

I've signed up to Gitlab using the connection they have with Google Accounts. Once that is made and I have permission to clone from a git repository, I try to clone using the https:// link (not the git: SSH one)

Now to complete this process, I am asked my username and password, but what is that in this scenario? Please don't recommend using SSH link instead as ssh is not straightforward on a Windows OS.

Comment: Refer [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53351575/814548). Its very simple.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Its very simple

- Login to gitlab (Using OAuth method)
- Go to https://gitlab.com/profile/password/edit
- It asks for **New password** and **Password confirmation** (If you are registered using OAuth method it will not ask for current password)
- Enter the password you want to set and click **Save Password** button

Done! You can now login with your email id and password.

Comment: Works for me. Why they don't direct you to set up a password for pushing is beyond me.

Comment: You can keep your gmail user, without @gmail.com, just the first part of the email address and select a new password.

Comment: link changed to https://gitlab.com/-/profile/password/edit

Answer (score 41):

You can actually use the https link if you login using a Google, Twitter or GitHub link but you have to have an actual GitLab password. If you've already created your account by logging in with a social network, all you have to do is use the Forgot Password feature.

1. log out and then use the "Forgot your password?" button and put in the email address of the social network you logged in with.
2. Once you get the email, "change" your password which will have actually set your GitLab password
3. You should now be able to use the https: clone url with your username and the password you just set.

Comment: I tried to reset just now but failed. The trick is have to logout first. You are the hero! The command line require username and password here though.

Comment: This is one of the stupidest designs I have ever seen. I would never have figured this out from experimentation. How did you discover this hack?

Comment: Solution worked, this design requires a password other-than SSO. :P

Comment: Is not required anymore. You can refer [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53351575/814548). Its very simple now.

Answer (score 1):

Go to setting - > passwords -> you can change/create password if you have created account via social media extension (google/twitter/fb) add any password in current password and add & confirm new password.

it works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't want to hear it: use ssh. ;)

Setting up ssh is not too much work on windows:

- [Download](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) the putty windows installer and run it to install all putty tools
- Run puttygen to generate a new key, save the private key on your disk
- Run pagent and load that key. (Optionally add pagent to autostart.)
- You might also need to set GIT_SSH=c:\Program Files\Putty\plink.exe

You have to do this only one. Afterwards everything should work without any more work.

Comment: Haha, actually you can also download TortoiseGit which comes with puttygen. That's what I did eventually for one of the users, and now it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Another potential solution:

1. Create a new account *from scratch* on Gitlab cloud
2. Go to your profile settings on this new account (your image on top right > Edit Profile Settings)
3. On Account tab activate your social account

You should now be able to use both your Gmail username and Gitlab password OR your Gitlab username/password.

Answer (score 0):

From GitLab:

> You can also use personal access tokens to authenticate against Git
> over HTTP. They are the only accepted password when you have
> Two-Factor Authentication (2FA) enabled.

To generate this token click your avatar -> Edit profile -> Access Token. The token can be named and has limited access (for example only read_repository). The token acts like a standard password.